# Force Logout all devices in mvc 4 application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have mvc 4 project with default Account Controller and UsersContext as DbContext. When a user, Suppose User1 logged in with REMEMBER ME checked on mobile. And next day User1 login in Laptop and changed its password, now User1 opened his mobile it is already logged in even when password is changed.

Is there any way by which i can force that User1 to Logout all the Devices,
without storing any session id in database?

Comment: If the user has changed his password, but is still an active user, then why is it a problem to log him in automatically? I hope you wouldn't log the user in if the user were disabled.

Comment: No, By Using MVC 4 Default Account Controller and database. Suppose if u login to site with your Friend's mobile with Remember me checked, and next day you changed your password using laptop. Then Even after password change In Your Friend's Mobile when your Friend open site, You already logged in, And He ( your friend) can access your account.

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind it, I just don't believe there is anything built into MVC that would provide this, I think you'd have to handle it on your own

Comment: I think the answer is to not check "remember me" when using your friend's mobile, nor any public computer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Can i code or set garbage value to that cookie ( Remember me ) When User Changes his password. So that other devices will not recognize that, and show login page again??

Comment: No, the cookie is stored on each device.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could store a "last password change date" in the cookie. On authentication, if the user has changed his password since the stored date, then do not authenticate the user.

You should probably store a hash of the last password change date, so that it can't be tampered with from the client side.

Comment: I have only permissions to code. and Not Allowed to change, Modify and field of database because database is on another Server.If it Requires a database modification A LOT OF PAPER WORKS AND PERMISSIONS ARE REQUIRED because its a Database of Govt.

Comment: I didn't suggest you should change the database. Isn't "last password change time" stored in the database already?

Answer (score 0):

Have a flag in the database that checks users on Session_Start that invalidates their session if that flag is set. May not necessarily use a boolean, you can use a DateTime value and invalidate all sessions that started prior to that time. This could be done by checking a value stored in a cookie upon login.

There is nothing built into ASP.NET MVC (that I know of) that provides this functionality

Comment: I can not modify the database, or its fields. I can Only Code. Is there any code through which i can Logout All the Other Devices. Like, User.LogoutAll() or code like that.

Comment: you would have to be maintaining some sort of session at the database level for it to really work correctly. There is nothing built into ASP.NET MVC (that I know of) that provides this functionality

Comment: Can i code or set garbage value to that cookie ( Remember me ) When User Changes his password. So that other devices will not recognize that?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic but I ran across this today.  The cause was slightly different, but I needed to do the same thing - log off a user if 'remember me' had been chosen.

The cause in my case was a change of database.  I changed the database name in my connection string (from a 'test' DB to a 'dev' DB), and I will still logged in after running the project, which caused a problem because the user did not actually exist in this new DB.

So in Global.asax I did the following:

```
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Session_Start()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var user = UserManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name);
            if (user == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                Response.Redirect("/", true);
            }
        }
    }
```

You need to redirect and terminate execution of the current page (by passing true) because (as I understand it) the sign out does not affect the current request, so the page that was loading will still load as if the user is logged in.  Anyone feel free to correct, clarify or expand upon this.